# Running ScalaTest in Play Framework 2.2.X

Tags: scala, playframework-2.2, scalatest

I'm trying to run some functional ScalaTest in Play 2.2 but can't seem to be able to import de @Test annotation needed to run the tests. I've tried looking for solutions but they seem to be from different versions since none work with my 2.2 version.

Can anyone guide me on running a ScalaTest some on play?

The super basic test class I tried to run is:

```
class Test extends AssertionsForJUnit {
  @Test def test() {
  }
}
```

While the error I get is:

> type mismatch; found : server.Test required:
>   scala.annotation.Annotation

Answer (score 0):

Can you paste an example of your test class? Also you need to include ScalaTest in the build file:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "2.1.0" % "test"
```

Comment: I did have the dependency. I update my main post with more info too.